# How do I only allow 1 third-party website to access my S3 object?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I been asked in interview - How give permission to only 1 third party website to access my S3 object ?

Say 1 third party web site there which uses our S3 object data on his website we just provide URL of our objects, so here how I can grant permission to only that third party website say www.thirdparty.com  such that if any one else tries should be denied.

Comment: So, since it is _your_ job interview, what do _you_ think the answer might be? What capabilities of Amazon S3 might be relevant? Do you know the various ways to grant access to objects/buckets in Amazon S3? How do you think each option be good or bad for this particular requirement? If you aren't sure, review the Amazon S3 Developer Guide — it's an eye-opening read!

Answer (score 2):

Use AWS S3 bucket policy to allow access from specific HTTP referrer (in your case, `www.thirdparty.com`).

You will need 2 statements in the policy:

- Allow `s3:GetObject` action from chosen referrer
- Disallow `s3:GetObject` action (or all actions) from other referrers

You can [see an example here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html) (`Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer`
 section)

Above instruction is for limiting access from client side (i.e: from `img`, `canvas`, etc.), if you want to access S3 objects on server side instead of client side, you will want `Restricting Access to Specific IP Addresses` example on above link instead

Comment: Thank you @Nam Tran  , so I need to add a bucket policy 'Restricting Access to Specific IP Addresses' topic in the link you shared resolved my query!

Comment: @sudhirtataraju They are 2 different cases:

1. Use `Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer` if you want to access S3 resource from client side (i.e: `img` tag, `canvas`, etc.)
2. Use `Restricting Access to Specific IP Addresses` if you want to access the S3 resource from server side